# Keyboard is disabled on boot up

Tags: raspbian, usb, keyboard

I've just installed a copy of noobs on my Pi. I then installed Raspbian.

When I boot up in recovery mode I can use my keyboard and mouse fine. However, when It boots normally I can see that it disables the usb port for some reason and it no longer works.

I'm using an apple keyboard. I've used this in the past but for some reason since I wiped the card and installed a fresh copy of Raspbian it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried a non-apple keyboard?

Comment: @lenik +1 Thinking the Apple keyboard is drawing too much power

Comment: With my RPi, I use a Logitech keyboard and often have to unplug and replug in the keyboard even though it registers on boot.

Comment: I've ordered a different keyboard so will try that. But I've used the apple keyboard previously with no problems.

Comment: unless you have a power supply able to provide steady 2-3A @ 5V you were most probably "balancing on the edge" and the new version of Raspbian with the new software running just tipped the scale to the wrong side.